# How do you associate your game play with your Rockstar Social Club account?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I have an Xbox live account, from which I play GTA. I also have a Rockstar social club account. However when I log into it, I don't see any statistics or even an indication that I own the game.

Within the GTA universe, I received the perks of having a social club account (free garages and GTR).

How are these two accounts associated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Rockstar Social Club, after logging in, look for [linked acccounts](https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/settings/linkedaccounts). From there, you'll be able to select the Xbox icon and begin the process of linking your 2 accounts. I do not know if linking an account after you played some will sync all your past progress, but I would assume it will.

Answer (score 0):

Previous Rockstar games asked you to sign up with your *Rockstar Social Club* account automatically, this is no longer the case with *GTA 5*.

What I did, was open the start menu, switch to the `Settings` tab, and select the `Facebook` option. You will be asked to sign up to the *Rockstar Social Club* before you can link your Facebook account to it.

You do not need a Facebook account, nor do you need to link it to your game at all; it is merely the only way I found to sign up to the *Rockstar Social Club* on *GTA 5*. It is possible that this will change upon release of *GTA Online*.

Comment: There is an easier way.  Link your xbox live account to your social club the game will eventually automatically link the game to your social club account

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, well in my case GTA 5 was the first Rockstar game I've played on the PS3, so my PSNID was never linked to my RSC one.

Comment: Same here didn't have a Social Club account before GTA5 thus if you link the account through a browser you have to do nothing in game